# Display the number of bytes, words and lines in a file

Tags: shell, files, wc

I want to create a shell script `df`. As, I want to type in `df name_of_file` and then I can get the contents of the file.

If the file name is in the directory, I want it to show its contents. If not, I want to show the size in words, lines, and bytes. How do I go about this? So far, I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$FILENAME
FILEBYTES=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")
FILEWORDS=$(stat -w%s "$FILENAME")
FILELINES=$(stat -l%s "$FILENAME")
echo "Size of $FILENAME in bytes = $FILEBYTES  bytes, $FILEWORDS words, $FILELINES lines."
```

Comment: What does it mean that 'If not, I want to show the size in words, lines, and bytes' when the file name isn't in the directory?

Comment: Please explain what you expect to happen when the file's present in the directory vs. not. What you've stated is contradictory "...file name is in the directory, I want it to show its contents. If not, I want to show the size..."

Comment: I actually meant that I do want all of that info when I do a df filename command. So, when I do df filename... I'd want it to display the contents

Comment: OK, that's kind of what I figured. Also what do you mean by filewords?

Comment: how many words are in the file, eek.

Comment: I need to show the number of lines, words, and bytes.

Comment: See my answer for a solution.

Comment: Why not simply use `wc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$1

[ -f "$FILENAME" ] || exit

FILEBYTES=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")
FILEWORDS=$(wc -w "$FILENAME" | awk '{print $1}')
FILELINES=$(wc -l "$FILENAME" | awk '{print $1}')

printf "Size of %s -- %s bytes, %s words, %s lines.\n" \
        "$FILENAME" "$FILEBYTES" "$FILEWORDS" "$FILELINES"
```

#### Example

Say I have this file:

```
$ ls -l | grep bbbb
-rw-rw-r--   1 saml saml    3283 May 18 02:49 bbbb
```

Now I run your script, I called it `df.bash`. The `df` command is already taken in Unix:

```
$ ./df.bash bbbb 
Size of bbbb -- 3283 bytes, 386 words, 94 lines.
```

Look for a file that doesn't exist:

```
$ ./df.bash bbbbbbb
$
```

#### Alternative method

You can save some wasted calls by consolidating and having `awk` do the counting instead of `wc`.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$1

[ -f "$FILENAME" ] || exit

FILEBYTES=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")
FILEWORDS=$(awk '{ total = total + NF }; END {print total}' "$FILENAME")
FILELINES=$(awk 'END {print NR}' "$FILENAME")

printf "Size of %s -- %s bytes, %s words, %s lines.\n" \
        "$FILENAME" "$FILEBYTES" "$FILEWORDS" "$FILELINES"
```

Comment: @Gary - you are very welcome. Thanks for your Q!

Comment: @jasonwryan - thanks I'll add those as alternative methods.

Comment: @Gary - you close the other Q before I could help you, To get a list of the top 5 words in a file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850823/calculate-word-occurrences-from-file-in-bash. Also if you need help come into the chat we can help you if you're stuck in there: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking for this?

```
 #! /bin/bash
 if [[ -f $(basename "$1") ]]
    then
       cat "$1"
    else
       wc -w -l -c "$1"
 fi
```

By the way, `df` is already a command to display disk space usage.  Better to call your script something else.

Comment: +1 for stating the obvious (`wc` does them all, no need for other tools). But why `wc -w -l -c "$1"` ? `wc "$1"` does the same...

Comment: Just as a reminder of the `wc` flags, so that it would be easy to edit the script to display only lines, for instance.